# Unable to make a GET request with AJAX under Node.js when using NGINX

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

Despite I have learned and implemented AJAX request with Node on my local server. I am finding that the requests that I created on my local server, just does not work at cloud server.

When I use AJAX to request data to the server (Node), the request does not get to the server because of the URL (or I think so).

Node Code:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

        app.get("/mypath/",function(req,res){
            console.log("please tell me that you arrive here"); //This actually never happens
            //some functions using the data in "req" and putting there in var "data"
            res.send(data);
        });
});
```

Javascript Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/mypath/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {//some data to use on the server},
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data){
          //some stuff with the transformed data
        },
    });
```

The code above works in the local server (my pc). But not in the cloud one, I had some problems trying to the server static files with NGINX and Express, but I was able to figure it out.

Do you think that given the way I am serving the static files and that I am working in the cloud server, I should use AJAX request in a different way when we are trying to communicate through an URL?

Console Log:

[Console Log after using Marcos solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vZ8n.png)

**EDIT: Code from jQuery AJAX and Node Request**

Node Set-Up:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var db = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io").listen(http);

http.listen(3000, 'localhost'); //At the end of everything between here and the code.
```

GET Node Code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/reqData',function(req,res){
    //I never arrive here
    console.log("print that I am here");
                transform(req.query.selection1,req.query.selection2,function(){
                res.json(data); //data is transformed globally  
                });

});
```

Ajax:

```
function requestData(){
     $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/reqData',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {//Some stuff to send},
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data){

              do(data);
            },
            error: function(e){

              console.log(e);
            }
       });

    }
```

**New Console Log:**
[Chrome Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8fOl.jpg)

Comment: `url` in your `$.ajax` request call is not a valid absolute URL. Is that the actual URL you're using?

Comment: Your URL is incorrect, no matter where you execute it. At a minimum, it should be `url: 'http://localhost:3000/mypath/'`

Comment: Also, the first thing you should always do is look in your browser's console for errors. Do you see any?

Comment: Hi @Jacob , the url was correct in the source code, the problem persists.

Comment: Hi @Phil , the url was correct in the source code, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you have, is how you're defining your routes, you will be unable to reach `/mypath/` until you perform a request first to `/`.

You should not define your routes that way, each route should be defined individually, and not in a nested way.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    // Set your cookies here, or whatever you want
    // This will happen before serving static files
    next(); // Don't forget next.
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/mypath/', (req,res) => {
    console.log("please tell me that you arrive here"); //This actually never happens
    //some functions using the data in "req" and putting there in var "data"
    res.send(data); // make sure it is defined.
});
```

And your route `app.get('/')` conflicts with `express.static(__dirname + '/')`, so you should just remove it if you're only serving an `index.html` file, which seems to be your case.

Then in your `$.ajax` you should add the protocol to the URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourdomain.com/mypath/',
    // url: 'http://localhost:3000/mypath/',
    /* ... */
});
```

Now, supposing you have everything else setup correctly, you will be able to access `/mypath`

Comment: Hi Marcos, if I do not put the express.static inside the app.get, I am not able to make app.get("/"... work. I do not know why it is happening.

Comment: Explain what does: `I am not able to make app.get work` means. Have you put `res.send('foo')` inside `app.get("/")` and see if you get that response?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have a res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

But into an IF (because I am checking req.sesision.visitor), I do not know if using cookies and cookie-parser is changin anything.

Comment: I have seen that if I put express to serve static files outside "app.get", then app.get("/") does not happen never.

Comment: Check updated answer, your route conflicts with `express.static` just remove `app.get('/')` which you don't need.

Comment: Perfect Marcos, however, I does not make any conflict with the cookies? This since I am using req.session.visitor to assing the sessions. I am doing it the wrong way?

Comment: You should set the cookies in another middleware, before `express.static`, check updated answer

Comment: Thanks Marcos. I've done that. However it seems that I am not able to serve static files with that solution, could you please check at the log I attached to my question? it is at the end.

Comment: The solution works perfectly, I'm testing it right now, you probably don't have an `index.js` at the root of your app. Post your full express code & your directory structure.

Comment: Marcos, everything is in the root (even the index.js file that I do have). Right now I do not have a directory structure, just a index.html, server.js and index.js in my root, another couple of files. I will see the way to put all the express code here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Marcos, I checked and I am not able to serve static files as my index.js if I add the express.static after app.get('*'). Only serves it if I add it before the app.get.

Comment: Have you added the next(); function call? And add your code if you want further help, I cannot guess your code. The code I. Provided works fine.

Comment: Yes I did, ok I will upload the code and let you know. Marcos, what do you think is the best middleware to use sessions? I am using right now express-session and cookie-parser.

Comment: Those two are just fine.

Comment: Hi @Marcos, it seems that the problem is solved for the cookies and the static files, however the problem about the route persists, do you think it is better to open a new question or do you prefer me to update this question?

Comment: Hi, Since it's out of scope of this question, please open a new question, it will also attract more users that may be able to help you. But please leave a link here so I can take a look. Don't forget to accept the answer here :)

Comment: Hi Marcos, actually I read the question again and you helped to solve something that wasn't the scope of the question, and thank you very much. I have added the missing code you suggested to see if may be I am doing something wrong. Do you think the configuration of nginx have you be posted too? Thanks.

Comment: Understood. I will accept your answer is correct (thing that I do not know how to do by the way). And open a new question with the edited part. Hopefully you will be able to comment on my mistakes. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Marcos, as promised, I am sending the new link with the new question. Finally, I have accepted your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826861/jquery-ajax-get-request-does-not-arrive-to-node-js-using-nginx